# The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect - when trying to readfile in go lang

Tags: arrays, string, go, file-handling

I want to read contents of text file.

When I am passing the file name as string like this:

```
stream, err = ioutil.ReadFile("sample.txt")
```

its working.
Its even working if do in this way:

```
filename := "sample.txt"
stream, err = ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
```

But when I get the value of filename from string array, it fails to get the file and throw the error: ***The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect***

```
filename := lines[1] //where lines[] is an array of strings
stream, err = ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
```

#### Debug information

```
fmt.Printf("%q\n", lines[1]) // output: mytext2.txt\r
```

Comment: Debug by adding this statement: `fmt.Printf("%q\n", lines[1])`.  My wild guess is that you will find  a `\n` at the end of the string.

Comment: Here is what I got: `mytext2.txt\r`

Comment: My guess was close. Trim the trailing \r.  Possible options: `strings.TrimSuffix(filename, "\r")`, `strings.TrimSpace(filename)`.  Show us how you got `lines`.  There might be a better fix.

Comment: thanks a lot @ThunderCat 

`strings.TrimSuffix(filename."\r")` worked

I got lines from using this code:
`stream, err := ioutil.ReadFile("firstfile.txt")
 if err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
 }
 readString := string(stream)`

Comment: @ThunderCat move to an answer so others can find it easily

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The application should trim the `\r` from the end of the string using
 `strings.TrimSuffix(filename, "\r")` or `strings.TrimSpace(filename)`.

If OP used `strings.Split(s, "\n", -1)` to create `lines`, then the trailing `\r` can also be avoided by splitting on `"\r\n"` instead.